# AWS EMR free usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop

I am very new to cloud based services. I want to try impala queries on AWS EMR and EC2. Is it possible, Can I create a free account for EC2/EMR. If yes then how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a tutorial about cloud computing resources, not a specific programming question

Comment: FWIW, the amount of resources you get as part of the free tier are not worth running Hadoop or Impala

Answer (score 2):

**Impala** is not available as a standard option in **Amazon EMR**.

You would probably need to launch your own Hadoop cluster on Amazon EC2 instances.

However, the [AWS Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) only provides micro-sized EC2 instances, which are not appropriate for a Hadoop cluster.